# How to store and retrieve passwords without being seen in the code using spock table

Tags: encryption, passwords, spock, geb

I am looking for some good approaches on storing passwords within the framework (groovy+geb+spock+selenium). Currently I am using encrypt and decrypt methods using Crypto.Cipher. However I would like to know if others have any good approaches to do it. Such as any other algorithms/techniques/tools?

It looks something like below:

```
def "test" (){

given:

when
Login(username,password)

then

where:
username | password 
"jass" | "testpass123" 

//"jass" |  decryptPassword("some encrypted value ") 

// instead of the actual password we are calling a 
// function "decryptPassword" which takes encrypted value and
// returns the actual key to the calling function.

}
```

Comment: What would the benefit of this be? If the password can be decrypted, it's not actually more secure than the plaintext was.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the password and store in the spock table. Write a separate method in other class for decrypt. Use the encrypted data. Call the decrypt method in password field instead of plain test.

More secure decrypt method should be converted as jar file and use it. So its difficult to find the decrypt algorithm.